# Окна в Терминале

Tags: windows, dos, java, c#

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите пожалуйста, существует ли библиотека для реализации окон в терминале? Например как в Far, Midnight Commander, NC, ImpulseTracker для DOS и т.п. Помню очень давно была библиотека для Турбо Паскаль вроде, но забыл как называлась. Может быть есть современная реализация Окон В Терминале, для .NET например или Jаva?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Charva](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/Screenshots.html)